# Comparison of Nodes in Java For Priority Qeue

Tags: java, nodes, priority-queue

I am getting an error when I add a node in priority I guess the error is in the comparison method, I have googled it a lot and got a solution to extend it with comparable but still no success, Getting following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(Unknown Source)
```

Following is my node class

```
class Node<T,Q extends Comparable<Q>>{

    T obj;
    private Node<T, Q> parent;

    public final Node<T, Q> getParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }
    public final void setParent(Node<T, Q> value)
    {
        parent = value;
    }


    private int cost;

    public final int getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }
    public final void setCost(int value)
    {
        cost = value;
    }


    private T state;

    public final T getState()
    {
        return state;
    }
    public final void setState(T value)
    {
        state = value;
    }


    private Q aciton;

    public final Q getAciton()
    {
        return aciton;
    }
    public final void setAciton(Q value)
    {
        aciton = value;
    }


    public final int compareTo(Object obj)
    {
        Node<T, Q> node = (Node<T, Q>)obj;
        if (node.cost > this.cost)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (node.cost < this.cost)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (node.cost == this.cost)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and here is the snippet where it is called

```
explored.add(n2);
                     ArrayList<Integer> stlist = expandStates(n2.getState(), transitions);
                    int ac = 0;
                    for (int i : stlist)
                    {
                        Node<Integer, Integer> n3 = new Node<Integer, Integer>();
                        n3.setState(i);
                        n3.setCost(1 + n2.getCost());
                        n3.setParent(n2);
                        n3.setAciton(ac);
                        ac++;

                        if (isExplored(i, explored) == true)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            frontier.add(n3);
                        }
```

Comment: `Node` itself doesn't implement `Comparable`. If you had an `@Override` annotation on your `compareTo` method it would probably have informed you about that.

Comment: You need your to implement comparable for your node class or provide a comparator at queue construction time. If you don't do it queue will be unable to sort your nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Node` doesn't implement `Comparable` interface. So `PriorityQueue` doesn't know between two nodes, which one has greater priority. You can change the signature of your class like this:

```
class Node<T, Q extends Comparable<Q>> implements Comparable<Node<T, Q>> {
    ...
    public final int compareTo(Node<T, Q> node)
    {
        if (node.cost > this.cost)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (node.cost < this.cost)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (node.cost == this.cost)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Notice that also the definition of `compareTo` is changed to take a node as an argument instead of a generic object.

Comment: if you think that the question can be useful in some way and can help someone kindly vote up please :)

Answer (score 1):

`Node` doesn't implement `Comparable`. You need: `class Node<T,Q extends Comparable<Q>> implements Comparable<Node<T , Q>>{`

Comment: Although it was so brief but +1 for help, if you think that the question can be useful in some way and can help someone kindly vote up please :)